# My attempt to define a hash_map variable is not working for me in VS2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, hashmap

I'm using Visual Studio 2008. This is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <conio.h>
#include <hash_map>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

hash_map <int, int> hm;

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

And here's my error:

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

Comment: you are not posting your real code, in your real code the hash_map types are not int/int, you need to provide default `operator <`

Comment: Basic spelling and punctuation. Even if you're not a native speaker, take some time to run a spell-checker and proof-read your code...

Comment: There's no `conio.h` and `hash_map` in C++

Comment: Er, the presentation may not be the best shining example, but lower quality questions have been answered and this is quite answerable (I have one written up now...). Voting to reopen.

Comment: There is no `hash_map` in C++. If you can afford to use a C++ implementation with C++11 support, you can use `unordered_map`. Otherwise, I am afraid you will have to look for a hashmap implementation somewhere other than the standard library.

Comment: @EduardoLeón Bullshit. The question is clearly tagged as [tag:visual-studio-2008] where those headers do, in fact, exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the MSVC compiler, extensions to the standard library are placed in the `stdext` namespace:

```
#include <hash_map>

stdext::hash_map<int, int> hm;

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

*Disclaimer: I don't own VS2008 but this should work. :)*

Note, though, that you should update to the latest compiler if possible and use the new standard unordered containers instead: `std::unordered_map` and `std::unordered_set`.